# How to reload custom cells forcefully in UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionviewcell

In a `UIViewController` , i have a `UICollectionView` & `UICollectionViewCells` contains charts([Piecharts  and Bar charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts)).

The chart's `delegates` and `datasource` are there in `UICollectionViewCell` and the `viewdidload` itself  loading charts from `NSUserdefault`.

**ISSUE:**

While new data come's how can we reload the cells. Already loaded cells are not  getting reloaded . its remains same with old data. But the cells which are not loaded earlier are loading with new data. How we can forcefully reload full cells with new data from `NSuserdefault` .

Comment: yourCollectionview.reloadData() Simple

Comment: While calling reload(). the data loaded cells remains same because the charts datasource are in cell subclass and its not redraw the cells with new data . simply keeping old draw with old data

Comment: @Abbut John do collectionviewname.reloadData() on main thread after gettinh your data.

Comment: The `array` or `dictionary` you are using for `UICollectionView`, after getting the data just remove all its previous values and assign new values and reload `UICollectionView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just get the array index in which you want to reload the cell.

```
[_collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
    [_collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath x inSection:0]]];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
```

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Set the data source and delegate of pichart inside the collection view cell for row at index path.